# Trim camera cable for pi 2 for Raspberry pi zero

Tags: camera, pi-zero, cable

I ordered a camera for my pi zero w and got the wrong one. Can it be trimmed to fit the zero’s smaller connectors

Comment: what is the pinout difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

The CSI port of the Zero W is smaller than that of the Pi 2 and 3. You will need an adapter cable to make it fit. I'd say it's rather complicated to DIY that.

See e.g. here: [Raspberry Pi Zero Camera Adapter](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-camera-adapter) or [Camera Cable - Raspberry Pi Zero edition](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/camera-cable-raspberry-pi-zero-edition) and others.

... and some nice additional information about the pinout is to be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=156098).

Comment: In a make do situation, removing unused pins looks feasible https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0174/1800/products/Camera_cable_3_of_3_-2_1024x1024.JPG

Comment: @LynnetteVining certainly so, but the outcome will be highly dependant on your skills and tools available. It may work or may not including the probability of killing both the Pi and the Camera. Is that chance worth a £4 adapter? But if you're up to it and going down that road feel free to post an answer documenting the result and the steps to get there. That'd be certainly a worthwhile answer.